# Reading a phrase with scanf

Tags: c, scanf

Im trying to create a program that interprets commands sent from a client to a server. My problem is i can only read the first word of the command.

**dict.h**

```
typedef struct
{
  pid_t pid_cliente;
  int status;
  char command[TAM_MAX];
  char secure[TAM_MAX];
  char password[TAM_MAX];
  int client_type;
} request;
```

**ClientSide**

```
  printf("[ADMIN]: ");
  scanf("%s[^\n]", buffer); //reads command
  printf("Sending -> '%s'\n", buffer);
  strcpy(request.command, buffer, MAX_SIZE-1)   //MAX_SIZE = 50
  write(server_fifo, & request, sizeof(request));
```

**ServerSide**

```
read_res = read(server_fifo, & request, sizeof(request));
if (read_res < sizeof(request))
        {
          if (!strncasecmp("exit",(char *) & request,4)) return;
          else
            {
              fprintf(stderr, "\nMessage Error!");
              return;
            }
        }  
token = strtok(request.command, " "); //reads command
printf("Command -> '%s'\n", token)

..
interprets wich command to do
..

token = strtok(NULL, " "); //reads command argument
printf("Argument -> '%s'\n", token);
```

**Input:**

```
addcity lisbon
```

**Output:**

```
Sending -> addcity
Sending -> lisbon

Command -> addcity
Argument -> (NULL)
```

Comment: how do you send and receive commands between client and server, give actual calls please..

Comment: Done, sorry about that

Comment: Check the return value of `read` and `write` calls. they mean how many bytes sent and received. If they are not same, read until receiving all required bytes. Append `NULL` to the received string and check it.. Provide `request` structure declaration for more clarity.

Comment: I have a if statment to compare with what read returns and the sizeof request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the scanf formmating.

```
scanf(” %[^\n]s”, buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not:

```
scanf("%s[^\n]", buffer);
```

as it only reads `%s` that is one everything until the first space, but

```
scanf("%[^\n]", buffer);
```

Comment: And that's why `fgets()` should be used insetad of `scanf()`.

Comment: in this particular case, yeah :)

Answer (score 0):

Your scanf format specification isn't matching your input.  This simple prototype does broadly what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf[64] = {0};
    printf("> ");
    scanf("%[0-9a-z ]", buf);
    printf(">> %s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the scanf format specification will read 0-9, a-z, and the literal
space (" ") character.  Capitalised words and other kinds of whitespace will
fool it!

For more flexible input handling you might want to try either read(2) into a
buffer and performing your own tokenization.  Something like flex/bison is
worth investigating -- although it may be overkill.  Depending on the
licensing restrictions on your application, GNU's readline library might also
be worth a look.

Comment: Thanks, i didnt noticed i was missing the format.
 I still have a problem, before i scanf the command, i have to login. After i login, when it is suposed to ask for the command, it sends the command right away even before i can enter any character.